# C Recursion segmentation fault

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

I am new to C and trying to do a maze problem where 0 and letters are passing points and 1 is a barrier.

My 2D maze array are below where the starting point is at(0,4) and every time I have to check for 4 directions (N,S,E,W), and I have also the path array (initially contains "0" as chars) where I will put the routes as "R" which is also the same size:

```
1111S11110       
0000010001
110100010d
t001111110
0100000001
0111111101
1111111101
00000D01T1
0111110001
0000E01110
```

I am using recursive solution for pathfinding and in total use 3 functions which are below:

```
int isSafe(char Mazearray[matrixSize][matrixSize],int x,int y){
    if(x >= 0 && x < matrixSize && y >= 0 && y < matrixSize && Mazearray[x][y] != '1'){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;


}

void MazeSolution(char Mazearray[matrixSize][matrixSize],int x,int y,char pathArray[matrixSize][matrixSize]){
    if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x,y,pathArray) == 0){
        printf("There does not exist a possible solution!!!");
    }
    else{
        int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
            for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; ++j){
                printf("%c",pathArray[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int recursiveMaze(char Mazearray[matrixSize][matrixSize],int x,int y,char pathArray[matrixSize][matrixSize]){
    if(x == exitX && y == exitY){
        pathArray[x][y] == 'E';
        return 1;
    }
    // check if the coordinate is safe to go(not 1)
    if(isSafe(Mazearray,x,y) == 1){
        pathArray[x][y] == 'R';
        // Move North
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x-1,y,pathArray) == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        // Move South
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x+1,y,pathArray) == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        // Move East
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x,y+1,pathArray) == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        // Move West
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x-1,y-1,pathArray) == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        pathArray[x][y] == '0';
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the `MazeSolution()`, the program terminates with error code 255 and segmentation fault. When I debugged the problem appears at `recursiveMaze()` function.

So that, starting from first if statement it does not execute and the other problem is it goes and comes back between south and north control points.

Comment: compile with -g and run under gdb (asumming on linux). THis will at least show the failing line

Comment: Your "west" is wrong. It should be strictly adjusting on the y-axis; not x. `x-1,y-1` is effectively a diagonal move. Regardless, include your code that builds your matrices; effectively a minimum, **complete** example that demonstrates your problem. Reading this code is pointless if you borked the code that loads the arrays and or primes the four global variables you're apparently using.

Comment: Are you sure you need the very last return 0....Could it be return 1 perhaps?  (As nothing happens so all is good?)

Comment: Thank you very much :) So,i have numofLines() function which counts the number of lines in maze.txt file in my main funtion(). and i call it in my main function like that:    MazeSolution(mazeArray,startX,startY,pathArray);

Comment: What is `pathArray[x][y] == 'E';` supposed to do? If you want to assign, it should be `=`. If you're comparing, it needs to be inside an `if` test.

Comment: There's nothing preventing infinite recursion. When you test North, it will then test South, which gets back to the same place, and then they'll go back and forth like this.

Comment: Concur with Barmar. That mistake is repeated in at least three places.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for the attention and that part is exit coordinates and assigns char E in my patharray for the route.

Comment: @HabilGanbarli No, it doesn't. That's the point. It's an unused expression. There is no assignment on that line, nor on the others that are using `==` where assignment is intended.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig, that is very kind of you.I corrected them but it is again the same error. Do you have any idea why the program stops working?

Comment: One obvious bug is that the "west" move check is moving on a diagonal rather than simply west.  Change `x-1,y-1` to `x,y-1`.

Comment: Tom Karzes yeah you are right i corrected it but the thing is that it does not check east or west control statements.Just between south and north

Comment: Thanks everybody for giving me ideas.That is really kind of you :), Found the errors.There was infinite recursion because the coordinate always getting back to (0,4) to starting point, from north to south and vice verse.And one main thing for this was i have not checked the tried places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a call sequence that leads to an infinite loop:

```
recursiveMaze(M, x, y, p)
   recursiveMaze(M, x-1, y, p)
       recursiveMaze(M, x-1, y, p) -> run to completion
       recursiveMaze(M, x+1, y, p) -> infinite loop
```

It is infinite because in the second recursive call, you increment back the value that had been decremented in the first recursive call, which takes you back to the same state as the initial call.